# How to insert data into mysql using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql database using Java. I am using the following code to fetch data from database and it is working fine.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DbTest {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{


    // Accessing Driver From Jar File
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //DB Connection
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");  

    // MySQL Query
    PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM jam WHERE id='1'");

    //Creating Variable to execute query
    ResultSet result=statement.executeQuery();

    while(result.next()){

        System.out.println(result.getString(2));

    }

  }


  }
```

To Insert data, I have tried the above code only replacing

```
PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM jam 
 WHERE id='1'");
```

with

```
 PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO jam(id,name) 
 VALUES ('','Charlie Sheen')");
```

But its showing some errors. Could you please tell me where is the problem in my code.

Thanks :)

Comment: What errors are you getting??

Comment: Please specify the error too.

Comment: Talking with a database from Java is much easier if you use an ORM framework like Hibernate instead of JDBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your primary key is auto increment,you can try this;

```
  PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO jam(name) 
     VALUES (?)");

    statement.setString(1,"Charlie Sheen");

statement.execute();
```

Comment: Using bound parameters like this is really important in a real-world application, where the data is provided by an end user. Google "Little Bobby Tables" for a humorous look at why this is the case. Also, statement.executeUpdate() instead of execute() will give you count of the number of rows actually inserted, though this is more important when doing updates than when doing inserts.

Comment: @mstzn Thank you very much. It is working now. Should I use `statement.execute();` for updating database as well?

Comment: statement.execute() => If you dont know which method to be used for executing SQL statements, this method can be used.statement.executeUpdate => Generally drob table or database, insert into table, update table , delete from table statements will be used in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to insert lots of records, use batch insert

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
     
    //...
     
    String sql = "INSERT INTO jam(id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");  
 PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
     
    for (Employee employee: employees) {
        ps.setString(1, employee.getId());
        ps.setString(2, employee.getName());
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
    connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use this (if the ID is auto-increment)

```
"INSERT INTO jam(name) VALUES ('Charlie Sheen')"
```

in any case, If you do not know the value of a specific int field I suggest not to write it into the query, it will be setted by default.

I think, if you set and INTEGER column = '', it could be a problem to the mysql.

usually, I do not put numbers inside the ->''

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public void save(@RequestBody EmployeeListModel employeeListModels) throws SQLException{

    Connection connection=MyDataSource.getConnection(); 

     try{

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into employee(Id,first_name,last_name,email) values (?,?,?,?)");
    List<EmployeeModel> employeeModels = employeeListModels.getModels();

    Iterator<EmployeeModel> iterator = employeeModels.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        EmployeeModel model = iterator.next();
        statement.setInt(1, model.getId());
        statement.setString(2, model.getFirstName());
        statement.setString(3, model.getLastName());
        statement.setString(4, model.getEmail());
        statement.addBatch();

    }

    int[] updates = statement.executeBatch();

    for(int i=0;i<updates.length;i++){
        if(updates[i] == -2){
            System.out.println("executed fail"+i);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("executed:"+i+"successful"+updates[i]+"updated");
        }


    }

    connection.commit();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
     }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```