# How to insert arraylist to MySQL Database on Android D Studio

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I want to insert my ArrayList to MySQL Database, but I don't know how to start.

This is my array that I want to insert.

```
public class item_order {

    String txt;
    String txt1;
    String txt2;

    public item_order(String txt, String txt1, String txt2) {
        this.txt = txt;
        this.txt1 = txt1;
        this.txt2 = txt2;
    }


    public String getTxt() {
        return txt;
    }

    public void setTxt(String txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
    }

    public String getTxt1() {
        return txt1;
    }

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {
        this.txt1 = txt1;
    }

    public String getTxt2() {
        return txt2;
    }

    public void setTxt2(String txt2) {
        this.txt2 = txt2;
    }





}
```

This is the data that I add to ArrayList `item_order` data;

```
    public static ArrayList<String> namai = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static  ArrayList<String> jumlahi = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> hargai = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> totali = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I'm finished with that, now I have no clue how to insert that arraylist to mysql database. Thanks.

Comment: Many many many similar questions answered on Stackoverflow (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760069/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-using-java). Read a tutorial by searching for one on via a search engine.

Comment: thank for the link..i just wanna send arraylist from my java to Php. and do insert database from php.